# Javascript: Collapse array of objects on property value, summing quantity property, retaining most recent

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Looking for a more "functional" way of achieving this...

I have an object of products that looks like this (note duplicate `skuid`'s)

```
"products": [
    {
      "skuid": "B1418",
      "name": "Test Product 1",
      "price": 7,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20181114,
      "quantity": 2
    },{
      "skuid": "B3446",
      "name": "Test Product 2",
      "price": 6,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20190114,
      "quantity": 2
    },{
      "skuid": "B1418",
      "name": "Test Product 1",
      "price": 7,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20180516,
      "quantity": 5
    },{
      "skuid": "B3446",
      "name": "Test Product 2",
      "price": 6,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20180411,
      "quantity": 11
    }
]
```

I want to create a new array that has a single object for each distinct `skuid` but that SUMS all the `quantity` values *and* retains the newest `lastOrderedDate`.

The final result would look like:

```
"products": [
    {
      "skuid": "B1418",
      "name": "Test Product 1",
      "price": 7,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20181114,
      "quantity": 7
    },{
      "skuid": "B3446",
      "name": "Test Product 2",
      "price": 6,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20190114,
      "quantity": 13
    }
]
```

I can do it with a bunch of forEach's and if's, but I'd like to learn a more concise way to do it.  Perhaps with a sort, then `reduce`?

Comment: Well you can probably be quite concise but the best approach to get an answer on SO would be to try it out and come back when sh** hits the fan. And if it works but you're not sure if your code could be improved, there's [Code Review @ SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a `Map` and get all values later as result set.

```js
const
    getGrouped = (m, o) => {
        var item = m.get(o.skuid);
        if (!item) return m.set(o.skuid, Object.assign({}, o));
        if (item.lastOrderedDate < o.lastOrderedDate) item.lastOrderedDate = o.lastOrderedDate;
        item.quantity += o.quantity;
        return m;
    };


var data = { products: [{ skuid: "B1418", name: "Test Product 1", price: 7, lastOrderedDate: 20181114, quantity: 2 }, { skuid: "B3446", name: "Test Product 2", price: 6, lastOrderedDate: 20190114, quantity: 2 }, { skuid: "B1418", name: "Test Product 1", price: 7, lastOrderedDate: 20180516, quantity: 5 }, { skuid: "B3446", name: "Test Product 2", price: 6, lastOrderedDate: 20180411, quantity: 11 }] },
    result = Array.from(data.products
        .reduce(getGrouped, new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since `skuid` is a string, what's the advantage of using a Map instead of a plain object here?

Comment: it is just another approach for grouping.

Comment: @jordan it guarantees O(1) lookup.

Comment: @NinaScholz Right, but what's the advantage?

Comment: @JonasWilms So does a plain object.

Comment: where is the problem for having two alternate methods for grouping with a key?

Comment: @jordanRunning no. Most engines will switch to a hashtable representation if you use the object like a hashtable, but they don't have to.

Comment: @JonasWilms "[T]hey don't have to." Alright, I'll grant you that. Which engines don't, then, in a case such as this one?

Comment: @jordan I dunno. But does that matter? If you use a Map, you know for sure that it'll use a hashtable.

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't say it was a problem; I just asked what the advantage is. You chose to implement it that way and I was curious what the reason is.

Comment: @JonasWilms Does it matter how JS engines actually in use in the wild are going to run your code? In my opinion, yes, it does.

Comment: @JordanRunning, the first thinking was, map has a fluent interface which works with reduce best, because you could set an entry and return the map in one step. As oposite of the object, where youset it and need another statement for retuning the object.

Comment: @nina If you would not use reduce, you would not have to return the Map / object at all ... :)

Comment: @jordan for sure it does. But the answer in this case is not that easy. I only know how V8 does it (briefly), it basically stores objects in three different memory models. Maybe it'll directly choose the hashtable version, maybe not, maybe it will switch to it after a few iterations, maybe not. For sure I could run this code and watch V8 doing the optimizations, or I just use Map and can go on, knowing that the engine will choose the representation I want.

Comment: @NinaScholz works great, thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create an object using `reduce()` whose keys will unique skuid and value will fist object with that `skuid`
- Use `forEach` on the array and increase the `quantity` property of corresponding object in object created object.
- Use `Object.values()` to get an array.

```js
const products = [ { "skuid": "B1418", "name": "Test Product 1", "price": 7, "lastOrderedDate": 20181114, "quantity": 2 },{ "skuid": "B3446", "name": "Test Product 2", "price": 6, "lastOrderedDate": 20190114, "quantity": 2 },{ "skuid": "B1418", "name": "Test Product 1", "price": 7, "lastOrderedDate": 20180516, "quantity": 5 },{ "skuid": "B3446", "name": "Test Product 2", "price": 6, "lastOrderedDate": 20180411, "quantity": 11 } ]

const res = products.reduce((ac,a) => (!ac[a.skuid] ? ac[a.skuid] = a : '',ac),{})

products.forEach(x => res[x.skuid].quantity += x.quantity)

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: This does not "retain the newest lastOrderedDate" as OP requested. It only works because the objects happens to be in chronological order.

Comment: @GifCo I think my output match the expected output.

Comment: it does not. Change the first object with skuid: 'B1418' to "lastOrderedDate": 20180414 and check your output. It will incorrectly use the older date for lastOrderedDate

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const DATA = [
    {
      "skuid": "B1418",
      "name": "Test Product 1",
      "price": 7,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20181114,
      "quantity": 2
    },{
      "skuid": "B3446",
      "name": "Test Product 2",
      "price": 6,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20190114,
      "quantity": 2
    },{
      "skuid": "B1418",
      "name": "Test Product 1",
      "price": 7,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20180516,
      "quantity": 5
    },{
      "skuid": "B3446",
      "name": "Test Product 2",
      "price": 6,
      "lastOrderedDate": 20180411,
      "quantity": 11
    }
];



const mergeStrategy = {
  quantity: (a, b) => a + b,
  lastOrderedDate: (a, b) => Math.max(a, b)
}

const mergeByStrategy = strat => a => b => {
  const c = Object.assign({}, a, b);
  return Object.keys(strat).reduce((acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = strat[k](a[k], b[k]);
    return acc;
  }, c);
}

const groupByWith = prop => merge => xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if (acc[x[prop]] === void 0) { acc[x[prop]] = x; }
  else { acc[x[prop]] = merge(acc[x[prop]])(x); }
  return acc;
}, {});




const mergeFunc = mergeByStrategy(mergeStrategy);
const groupData = groupByWith('skuid')(mergeFunc);

console.log(Object.values(groupData(DATA)))
```

`mergeStrategy` defines *how* certain properties are merged. You can define as much properties/functions here as you like.

The `mergeByStrategy` function first takes a strategy (see above), and then two objects to merge. Note that it takes the objects in a curried form. It creates a *shallow copy* of both objects which it modifies according to the given strategy. This ensures your original data is still intact.

The `groupByWith` function takes a property name, a merging function and an array of objects and creates a dictionary/POJO/hashmap/call-as-you-like where each object is stored by the given property name. If there already exists an entry in the dictionary, it uses the merging function to combine the existing entry with the new entry, otherwise is simply stores the new entry into the object.